# Cannot locate database or application location on device

Tags: android

I cannot seem to locate the database of an application installed via Android Studio on a tablet. I have search in the Android/data folder and do not even see the package name of the application

Comment: then most probably your database is not created yet

Comment: I have checked and confirmed that the database is created programmatically by viewing the saved records from the application itself

Comment: clear cache and try again

Comment: If you have an unrooted device then you can't access the data folder. For un rooted device and only for testing purpose you can create database on external storage

Comment: Maybe the app creates the database somewhere else. I.e.: online or on some path in the device storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database files for an app are in the folder `/data/data/<application-id>/databases/` e.g. `/data/data/com.example.app/databases` if the application id is `com.example.app`.

Comment: The /data folder in my device is empty

Comment: Did you use su? Only the root user can view the /data folder. If you're on a real device and it's not rooted, you are out of luck.

Comment: Let me look into that, I know the device is not rooted and I have just  checked to confirm that the database location  /data/data... exists or not via ADB. It finds the path but no data is contained within.

Comment: The database cannot be seen directly from browsing the folders, so I coped the database to a location I could observe in Tablets file system

Answer (score 0):

After several unsuccessful attempts to root the device I eventually pursued writing to the sdcard which was no hassle whatsoever. Rooting the device would have caused some security and warranty issues anyway. Thank you for assistance provided.